# Strange Windows 7 dock icon hover behaviour

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

Something weird is happening to my new windows 7.

When I hover over an icon in the taskbar/dock it glows and the application title appears, and when I remove the cursor it stays glowing and it's really distracting.

But sometimes it just pops up the application list, like the box that appears above the icon, and it doesn't glow when i remove the mouse.

I prefer the later, but it keeps alternating between the two.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself.

In case you are having the same problem apparently shift + right clicking an icon fixes this.

Why this bug exists and remains unfixed, I don't know.